# VBA msgbox yes/no then do something

Tags: excel, vba

These are the two versions I tried using. They both fire when I want, but they aren't changing any values when I click yes. Also it gets stuck in an infinite loop and I have to CTRL+BREAK

```
If Target.Column = 6 And Len(Target.Value) > 1 Then
       For Each locationIdcell In locationIdRange
        If locationIdcell.Value <> Target.Value Then
      '  Dim answer As Integer
        Dim answer As Long
           answer = MsgBox("This Machine Has an attachment tied to it, Move Attachment with Machine?", vbYesNo)
           If answer = vbYes And locationIdcell.Value <> Target.Value Then
                bucketsAttachWorksheet.Cells(locationIdcell.Row, 6).Value = movesWorksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 9).Value
             Else ' do nothing
               MsgBox ("Attachments will stay in current location")
             End If
        End If
       Next locationIdcell
```

```
If Target.Column = 6 And Len(Target.Value) > 1 Then
        For Each locationIdcell In locationIdRange
         If locationIdcell.Value <> Target.Value Then
       '  Dim answer As Integer
        ' Dim answer As Long
            Select Case MsgBox(Prompt:="This Machine Has an attachment tied to it, Move Attachment with Machine?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
            Case vbYes
                 bucketsAttachWorksheet.Cells(locationIdcell.Row, 6).Value = movesWorksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 9).Value
            Case vbNo ' do nothing
                MsgBox ("Attachments will stay in current location")
            
         End If
        Next locationIdcell
    End If
```

Comment: Would be helpful to provide the full method.  It's not clear from what you posted if this is part of an event handler, and if so which sheet the code is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

1. You seem to be needlessly checking locationIdcell.Value <> Target.Value twice.
2. You don't need the variable you're reading the MsgBox response into, (and you should not be declaring variables in the middle of loop, but at the top of the procedure).
3. You're not closing your initial If..., and I'm not clear what it does.

However, here's a first pass for you and I'll happily update it if you can provide further clarifications:

```
If Target.Column = 6 And Len(Target.Value) > 1 Then
  For Each locationIdcell In locationIdRange
    If locationIdcell.Value <> Target.Value Then
      If MsgBox("This Machine Has an attachment tied to it, Move Attachment with Machine?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        bucketsAttachWorksheet.Cells(locationIdcell.Row, 6).Value = movesWorksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 9).Value
      Else ' do nothing
        MsgBox ("Attachments will stay in current location")
      End If
    End If
  Next locationIdcell
End If
```